# Finding deltas between two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, lets call them Table A and Table B. Both different sizes but have the same primary Key (ID). The variable field is (Name). I want to return rows from Table B that:

1. Data has changed
2. Data did not exist before

The returned data would have  an additional column labelled comments with the value set to above each time the SQL executes. I have written the T-SQL below, however is there a better way to do this?

```
SELECT [ID]
,[Name]
,'Data did not exist before' AS [Comment]
FROM TABLENAMEB
WHERE [ID] NOT IN (SELECT [ID] FROM #TABLENAMEA)
UNION
SELECT B.[ID]
,B.[Name]
,'Data has changed' AS [Comment]
FROM  TABLENAMEB B
LEFT JOIN TABLENAMEA A ON B.[ID] = A.[ID] 
WHERE A.[Name] != B.[Name]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES(1,'test1'),(2,'test2'),(4,'test4');

DECLARE @tblB TABLE(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblB VALUES(2,'test2'),(3,'test3'),(4,'different');

SELECT CASE WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN 'missing in A'
            WHEN B.ID IS NULL THEN 'missing in B'
            WHEN A.Name<>B.Name THEN 'different'
            ELSE 'okay' END AS Comment
            ,*
FROM @tblA AS A
FULL OUTER JOIN @tblB AS B ON A.ID=B.ID
```

The result

```
Comment         ID    Name  ID      Name
missing in B    1     test1 NULL    NULL
okay            2     test2 2       test2
different       4     test4 4       different
missing in A    NULL  NULL  3       test3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use left join and `case` to get the same result:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Name]
      ,CASE 
       WHEN A.[Name] IS NULL THEN -- Assuming `Name` in table a is not nullable.
           'Data did not exist before'
       WHEN B.[Name] != A.[Name THEN 
           'Data has changed'
       ELSE 
           ''
       END As [Comment]
FROM TABLENAMEB As B
LEFT JOIN #TABLENAMEA As A ON B.[ID] = A.[ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just noticed you are using 2008.  The features below will not be of any use.

You are writing this in T-SQL, thus you are using SQL Server.  Look into either of these two features specifically designed to answer your question:

1. Change Data Capture
2. Temporal Tables